# Setting up integration testing environment with KeyCloak in Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm trying to setup integration testing environment for one of our Web API project that secured with KeyCloak. My idea is create the docker compose file where connect all required components and then try to call Web API hosted in contained and validate the response.

Here is the example of docker compose file that connect KeyCloak and Web API together

```
keycloak:
  image: jboss/keycloak:3.4.3.Final
  environment:
    DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
    KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
    KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak
    POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR: postgres
    POSTGRES_DATABASE: keycloak
    JDBC_PARAMS: 'connectTimeout=30'
  ports:
    - '18080:8080'
    - '18443:8443'
  networks:
    - integration-test
  depends_on:
    - postgres

test-web-api:
    image: test-web-api
    environment:
    - IDENTITY_SERVER_URL=https://keycloak:18443/auth/realms/myrealm
    networks:
    - integration-test
    ports:
    - "28080:8080"
```

Now, when I host KeyCloak and Web API in different containers I can't get access from Web API container to KeyCloak using the localhost, so I need to use https://keycloak:18443/ but when I try it and get for example .well-known/openid-configuration from KeyCloak I get connection refused error:

root@0e77e9623717:/app# curl https://keycloak:18443/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
curl: (7) Failed to connect to keycloak port 18443: Connection refused

From the documentation I figured out that I need to enable SSL on KeyCloak but the whole process is a bit confused and it's not very clear what domain to use for the certificate...

If somebody had any experience with the situation like mine and could share it that would be great!

Comment: How's this working out for you? I'd like to know if it is a good practice to setup keycloak in a CI/CD pipeline and make integrations tests for the app that uses it. Maybe is better to just mock it? I'm using keycloak to authenticate and authorize user in a Spring Boot app.

Comment: well, it'a actually worked pretty well in my case. We had a test specific test keycloac image with predefined list of users with different permissions that we used for different calls and it worked as a charm! Did use it in several projects already. I'm not a big fan of mocking functionality and every time when I have an option to use real component I will definitely use it :)

Comment: I just started to use keycloak and was thinking about making IT with it. Just to make sure,  in the tests you are importing a keycloak config (with users) ? I saw that you're using Postgres for the keycloak server, maybe we can use the default in-memory database just for tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how did you configure `integration-test` network and where are you running your integration tests (host, container) to get the exact answer.

But I try. For keycloak access from the host:

```
https://<host IP or name>:18443/
```

From the container in the `integration-test` network:

```
https://keycloak:8443/
```

So try to configure `test-web-api`:

```
IDENTITY_SERVER_URL=https://keycloak:8443/auth/realms/myrealm
```

and your test-web-api should be able to reach keycloak.